# Creating one event from another - do I have memory leak?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qevent

Who is responsible for managing events ?

For the following code:

```
bool MyView::gestureEvent(QGestureEvent *event)
{
    if (QGesture *hold = event->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))
        holdTriggered(static_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture *>(hold));
    return true;
}

void MyView::holdTriggered(QTapAndHoldGesture *event)
{
    QPoint currentTouchPointPos = event->position().toPoint();
    QContextMenuEvent *event1 = new QContextMenuEvent(
                QContextMenuEvent::Mouse, currentTouchPointPos,
                currentTouchPointPos, Qt::NoModifier);
    QGraphicsView::contextMenuEvent(event1);
}
```

I ran it under Valgrind and it told me I have a memory leak.

Which is the leak, `event` or `event1` ?

Should I delete one of them, or both ? Or do I need to accept or ignore them ?

(I tried deleting `event1` because it is the one I created, and Valgrind still said I had a memory leak; but `event` is really passed from the caller so I should not touch it, I think - and even about `event1` I am not sure - will not sending it to `QGraphicsView` take care of it ?)

Comment: You should delete `event1` by yourself because you own it. If you would posted it via `QCoreApplication::postEvent` then you won't have to delete it. Not clear about `QGestureEvent* event` and `QTapAndHoldGesture *event` because we don't know how you manage them in caller.

Comment: I don't call events.